# How to delete all files inside subfolders, but not subfolders itselves?

Tags: command-line, trash

I know how to recursively delete all subfolders and all files. But in this case, I need to preserve subfolders. Basically, I need to empty them all.

So, I have

```
rootdir/
        subA/           
        subB/
        subC/
        subN/
```

And I want to delete all files inside `subA` to `subN`, but without deleting `subA`...`subN`

What is console command for this? I guess it's a switch to `rm`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `find` command to identify only regular files (type `f`) recursively

```
find rootdir -type f
```

If that shows the results you expect, then to actually delete them

```
find rootdir -type f -delete
```

NB this is a real delete not a "move to trash" so be 100% certain that it's what you really want to do before executing the command.

Comment: It seems it works, except I navigate to a dir I am currently in `find ./ -type f -print`. Any way not to do permanent delete but to send to trash?

Comment: @ubuntico if you have a newer version of regular Ubuntu, you should be able to use  `gvfs-trash`: specifically, replace `-delete` by `-execdir gvfs-trash {} +`

Comment: I have 14.04 and this trash command works.

Answer (score 2):

Building on steeldriver's answer, you can add xargs so that there is only one call to gvfs-trash.  in his example, `find` will call `gvfs-trash` once for every file found by `find`.  This might be slow if there are a lot of files:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 gvfs-trash
```

Comment: If you are referring to the example in the comment, the `+` indicates that `gvfs-trash` will be called with multiple filenames, so it is equivalent to your `xargs` command.

Comment: aha!  I didn't know that.  well I guess this isn't very useful then

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the `rm` command, but you would have to do this repeatedly.

you can first `cd`to the parent directory with this

`cd /rootdir`

after that you will have to run

`rm -rf ./folder/*`

Replace folder with the name of the folder you want to empty (eg. subA).

Repeat this until all folders are empty.

Note that `-rf` will remove also remove all the folders inside the folder you want to empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `-exec` like this: `find rootdir -type f -exec rm {} \;` (note that backslash is essential)